# Make the lower and upper estimate of quantity of fuel during the half hour

Tags: calculus

A car speeds up at a constant rate from $10$ to $70$ mph over a period of half hour. It fuel efficiency increase with speed, value are in the table. Make the lower and upper estimate of quantity of fuel during the half hour

Speed (mph) 10  20  30  40  50  60  70

Fuel (mpg)  15  18  21  23  24  25  26

So I think I should do the left and the right hand sum

$LHS=10\frac{1/15 +1/18+1/21+1/23+1/24+1/25}{2}=1.47 $g/half hour

$RHS=10\frac{1/26 +1/18+1/21+1/23+1/24+1/25}{2}=1.39 $g/half hour

So the $LHS$ is the upper estimate and $RHS$ is the lower? I'm not sure if I understand or did the problem correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are close to the intended solution.  In the first five minutes, you accelerate from $10$ to $20$ mph.  If you had traveled a steady $10$ mph for those five minutes, you would have gone $\frac {10}{12}$ miles and consumed $\frac {10}{12 \cdot 15}$ gallons of gasoline.  If you had traveled a steady $20$ mph for those five minutes, you would have gone $\frac {20}{12}$ miles and consumed $\frac {20}{12 \cdot 18}$ gallons of gasoline.  The two corrections that need to be made are to make the $2$ in the denominator $12$ because the interval is $1/12$ hour for each rectangle and to make the $10$ out in front reflect the speed.  I think this will make the RHS estimate higher because the assumed speeds are higher.